# Charts in Visual force

Tags: visualforce

Im trying to build a  simple and basic charts using visual force .I am not getting any error  but the chart is not getting displayed .I couldn't figure out the reason.
This is my controller:

```
    Public class AccountContacts
    {
        string ncontacts;
         public list<count> getAccount()
         {
         list<Account> ac = [Select id,name ,(Select id ,firstname from Contacts)from Account];

    list<count> conco=new list<count>();
    for(Account acc:ac)     
    {
        list<contact> conco1=new list<contact>();

        for(Contact c :acc.Contacts)
        {
           conco1.add(c);
        }
        count cc =new count(acc.name,conco1.size());
        conco.add(cc);

    }
    system.debug('list::'+conco);
    return conco;

}
public class count
{
    string accname{get;set;}
    integer count{get;set;}
    public count(string accname,integer count)
    {
        this.accname=accname;
        this.count=count;
    }

}
}
```

and my visual force page is

```
   <apex:page controller="AccountContacts"  showChat="False">
   <apex:pageBlock title="Count of Contacts" >
       <apex:chart height="200" width="200" data="{!Account}">
       <apex:pieSeries tips="True" dataField="data" labelField="naname"/>
       <apex:legend position="bottom"/>       
      </apex:chart>
  </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:page>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser's JavaScript console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to try is to use the actual names of the fields of your `count` object in the apex:pieSeries (oh and make the fields `public` in the class):

```
<apex:pieSeries tips="true" dataField="count" labelField="accname"/>
```

You can see this pattern used in e.g. [A Simple Charting Example](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_charting_overview_simple_example.htm).

FYI, a simpler form of your `getAccount` method is also possible:

```
public list<count> getAccount()
{
    list<count> counts = new list<count>();
    for(Account acc : [Select name, (Select id from Contacts) from Account limit 1000])     
    {
        counts(new count(acc.name, acc.Contacts.size()));
    }
    return counts;
}
```